# Error using '#' symbol in 'preg-replace()' function

Tags: php, preg-replace, delimiter

I get an error,

```
Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '#' found
```

on this line,

```
$sql = preg_replace("\n#[^\n]*\n", "\n", $sql);
```

on this function,

```
function split_sql($sql) {
    $sql = trim($sql);
    $sql = preg_replace("\n#[^\n]*\n", "\n", $sql);

    $buffer = array();
    $ret = array();
    $in_string = false;

    for($i=0; $i<strlen($sql)-1; $i++) {
        if($sql[$i] == ";" && !$in_string) {
            $ret[] = substr($sql, 0, $i);
            $sql = substr($sql, $i + 1);
            $i = 0;
        }

        if($in_string && ($sql[$i] == $in_string) && $buffer[1] != "\\") {
            $in_string = false;
        }
        elseif(!$in_string && ($sql[$i] == '"' || $sql[$i] == "'") && (!isset($buffer[0]) || $buffer[0] != "\\")) {
            $in_string = $sql[$i];
        }
        if(isset($buffer[1])) {
            $buffer[0] = $buffer[1];
        }
        $buffer[1] = $sql[$i];
    }

    if(!empty($sql)) {
        $ret[] = $sql;
    }
    return($ret);
}
```

Comment: @rae1n It's the question title.

Comment: @rae1n Are we `going` to `argue` semantics? It's the cause of the OP's problems and the reason why it's not working as expected. What error are you expecting? There are no more valid errors to return from the OPs code that would help in debugging this at all.

Comment: I'm arguing OP should put a bit more effort so someone else can help the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiter must be a non-alphanumeric, non-whitespace character. It is seeing the `#` as the delimiter for this reason, and therefore looks for another one and can't find it.

Try `preg_replace("/\n#[^\n]*\n/","\n",$sql);`